# Error while applying security patch SUPEE-7405 V1

Tags: security, patches, ee-1.13, supee-7405

> $ sh PATCH_SUPEE-7405_EE_1.13.1.0_v1.sh

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...

> ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/Checkout/Block/Adminhtml/Manage/Form/Coupon.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/Checkout/Block/Adminhtml/Manage/Form/Coupon.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pbridge/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pbridge/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/Model/Observer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/Model/Resource/Admin/User.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/Model/Resource/Admin/User.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/Pci/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/Persistent/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/Persistent/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/SalesArchive/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/WebsiteRestriction/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Enterprise/WebsiteRestriction/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php.rej
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Redirectpolicy.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Tab/History.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Catalog/Product/Edit/Action/Attribute.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/File.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image/Favicon.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php.rej
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Admin.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Helper/Data.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/PaymentController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php.rej
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Input/Filter/MaliciousCode.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/CustomerController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 146 (offset 9 lines).
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml.rej
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/system.xml,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Observer.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Queue.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/PayflowadvancedController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Persistent/etc/config.xml.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/Catalog/Salesrule.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Order.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
4 out of 4 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php.rej
patching file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/authorizenet/directpost/iframe.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/creditmemo/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/invoice/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/order/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/create/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/bundle/sales/shipment/view/items/renderer.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/creditmemo/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/invoice/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/downloadable/sales/items/column/downloadable/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/enterprise/checkout/form/coupon.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/renderer/default.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals/discount.phtml
patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 111 (offset 27 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 152 (offset 27 lines).
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml
patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
patching file lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

**EDIT**

All the php files were updated which are saying

> Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
>       Apply anyway? [n]
>       Skipping patch.
>       1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file

and other `.phtml` **files which doesn't say anything were not updated**

**What is the problem?**
In my localhost it applied successfully

Comment: Did you apply all the previous patches ?

Comment: yes except SUPEE-7616 which address USPS method. However this patch(SUPEE-7616) doesn't effect in my localhost. it(SUPEE-7405, V1) applied successfully

Comment: Please compare the `app/etc/applied.patches.list` of both your localhost and your server to ensure they're the same

Comment: yes they are same

Comment: can you please let me know how to select yes [y] for already applied patching file

Comment: Pressing y key is the way to go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36265/discussion-between-prasad-maganti-and-digital-pianism).

Comment: @DigitalPianism i have updated my question, your thoughts on this...

Answer (score 2):

Please install the `SUPEE 7405 v1.1` patch and your issue should be sorted out.

Comment: before installing SUPEE 7405 V1.0 how can we install V1.1?